# defcustom values for selecting from function call?

Tags: defcustom

I have definition:

```
(defvar my/python-checker-alist
  '((pylint . (my/python-pylint-command my/python-pylint-args))
    (pep8 . (my/python-pep8-command my/python-pep8-args))
    (pyflakes . (my/python-pyflakes-command my/python-pyflakes-args)))
  "Known Python source code checkers.")
```

Default checker defined in:

```
(defcustom my/python-default-checker 'pyflakes
  "Default Python source code checker. See `my/python-checker-alist' for full alist."
  :group 'my/python
  :type 'symbol)
```

I would like to restrict user choice in <kbd>M-x customize-group</kbd> to only symbols from list:

```
'(pyflakes pylint pep8)
```

***(1)*** How can I do this?

***(2)*** What if I want to access alway up to date values? Can I specify function reference of lambda, like this:

```
(lambda () (mapcar 'car my/python-checker-alist))
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Standard Info workflow

Here's how to get the info that you need:

1. `<f1> i` to start Info.
2. `g (elisp) RET` to select the Elisp node.
3. `i defcustom RET` to search the index for `defcustom`.

Immediately you'll see:

> ‘:type TYPE’
>       Use TYPE as the data type for this option.  It specifies which
>       values are legitimate, and how to display the value (*note
>       Customization Types::).

and:

> ‘:set SETFUNCTION’
>        Specify SETFUNCTION as the way to change the value of this option
>        when using the Customize interface.  The function SETFUNCTION
>        should take two arguments, a symbol (the option name) and the new
>        value, and should do whatever is necessary to update the value
>        properly for this option (which may not mean simply setting the
>        option as a Lisp variable); preferably, though, it should not
>        modify its value argument destructively.  The default for
>        SETFUNCTION is ‘set-default’.
>
> ```
>  If you specify this keyword, the variable’s documentation string
>  should describe how to do the same job in hand-written Lisp code.
> ```

### My shortcut for the above.

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `counsel-info-lookup-symbol` `defcustom` <kbd>RET</kbd>
will bring you to the same info page.

### Sample code for :type

```cl
(defcustom avy-keys-alist nil
  "Alist of avy-jump commands to `avy-keys' overriding the default `avy-keys'."
  :type '(alist
          :key-type (choice :tag "Command"
                     (const avy-goto-char)
                     (const avy-goto-char-2)
                     (const avy-isearch)
                     (const avy-goto-line)
                     (const avy-goto-subword-0)
                     (const avy-goto-subword-1)
                     (const avy-goto-word-0)
                     (const avy-goto-word-1)
                     (const avy-copy-line)
                     (const avy-copy-region)
                     (const avy-move-line))
          :value-type (repeat :tag "Keys" character)))
```

### Sample code for :set

```cl
(defcustom ediff-diff-options
  (if (memq system-type '(ms-dos windows-nt)) "--binary" "")
  "Options to pass to `ediff-diff-program'.
If Unix diff is used as `ediff-diff-program',
then a useful option is `-w', to ignore space.
Options `-c', `-u', and `-i' are not allowed. Case sensitivity can be
toggled interactively using \\[ediff-toggle-ignore-case].
Do not remove the default options. If you need to change this variable, add new
options after the default ones.
This variable is not for customizing the look of the differences produced by
the command \\[ediff-show-diff-output]. Use the variable
`ediff-custom-diff-options' for that."
  :set 'ediff-set-diff-options
  :type 'string
  :group 'ediff-diff)
```

Comment: Thanks for help. I already read info topics but never have experience and so didn't able to combine that knowledge. +1

Comment: (Or if you are in a buffer with Emacs-Lisp mode, just `C-h S defcustom`, to get to its doc in the Elisp manual.)

Comment: I can't see how this addresses the Q which is how to select from a list of values. we have to hard code multiple options?

Answer (score 0):

I added:

```
PROPOSAL: Is there a way to update available choices for defcustom variable?
```

http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?archive=yes&bug=22703

Seems that defcustom API doesn't reevaluate `:type`.

As proposal I ask about accepting function (lambda) as value of `:type`. In that case `:type` may be evaluated when widget build on <kbd>M-x customize-XXX</kbd>

Comment: I think the `restricted-sexp` type can satisfy this requirement

Comment: I didn't completely understand purpose of `restricted-sexp`. It has only one **active** parts: predicates applied over user input. It doesn't make actual choice for user. but rather verify user input.

Comment: oh, I misunderstood what you meant by "function as value of `:type`".